# Using toString() method from child class

Tags: java, polymorphism

Hi I am writing a code using polymorphism and I would like to print List on the screen but when I am using my code it run toString method from parent class only. How can I fix it?

public class HospitalApp {

```
public static void main(String[] main){

    Hospital hospital = new Hospital();

    List<Person> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    lista = hospital.showList();


    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for(Person person : lista){
        stringBuilder.append(person);
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

}

---

public class Hospital{

```
List<Person> lista = new ArrayList<>();
Person doktor = new Doctor("All", "Bundy",100, 99999);
Person nurse = new Nurse("Iga", "Lis",160, 10);
Person nurse_1 = new Nurse("Magda", "Andrych",160, 20);

public List showList(){
    lista.add(doktor);
    lista.add(nurse);
    lista.add(nurse_1);
    return lista;
}
```

}

---

public class Person{

```
private String imie;
private String nazwisko;
private double wyplata;

public Person(){}

public Person(String imie, String nazwisko, double wyplata){
    this.imie = imie;
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    this.wyplata = wyplata;
}

public void setImie(String imie){
    this.imie = imie;
}

public String getImie(){
    return imie;
}


public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko){
    this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
}

public String getNazwisko(){
    return nazwisko;
}


public void setWyplata(double wyplata){
    this.wyplata = wyplata;
}

public double getWyplata(){
    return wyplata;
}


public String toString(){
return  getImie() + " " + getNazwisko() + " " + getWyplata();
}
```

}

---

public class Nurse extends Person{

```
private int nadgodziny;

public Nurse(){}
public Nurse(String imie, String nazwisko, double wyplata, int nadgodziny){
    super(imie, nazwisko, wyplata);
    this.nadgodziny = nadgodziny;
}


public void setNadgodziny(int nadgodziny){
this.nadgodziny = nadgodziny;
}

public int getNadgodziny(){
    return nadgodziny;
}

@Override
String toString(){
return  getImie() + " " + getNazwisko() + " " + getWyplata() + " " + getNadgodziny();
}
```

}

---

public class Doctor extends Person {

```
private double premia;


public Doctor(){}

public Doctor(String imie, String nazwisko, double wyplata , double premia){
    super(imie, nazwisko, wyplata);
    this.premia = premia;
}


public double getPremia(){
    return premia;
}

public void setPremia(double premia){
    this.premia = premia;
}

@Override
String toString(){
return  getImie() + " " + getNazwisko() + " " + getWyplata() + " " + getPremia();
}
```

}

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve] illustrating your problem.

Comment: your `toString` methods in `Nurse` and `Doctor` classes aren't `public`. Making them  public will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here, in the `Person` and `Doctor` class:

```
@Override
String toString(){
    return  ...;
}
```

you are missing the `public` specifier. There should be an error / warning about that. Apply it to the method signatures and your code will work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should add to the List not a Person (object) but a value returned by its toString method:
`for(Person person : lista){
        stringBuilder.append(person.toString);
        stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }`

Comment: "Probably" is rarely a good way to start an answer. Plus, if you read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.Object-), you'd realise that your answer is incorrect.